# is this correct way to calculate days in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

in above table number of `email` there and `times` i want to add there time in days according to email but this is not working ..

```
<?php if(count($client)): ?>
  <?php $days=0;
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    ?>
   <?php foreach ($client as $clents):?>
    <?php
     if($clents['email']==$clents['email']){
     $today = time();
    $cdate = strtotime($clents['times']);
    $dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
    $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    $dayscalculate = 30 - $fullDays; // Set number of days ?>

     <?php $day=$dayscalculate; 
    $days +=$day;
   }
   ?>

    <tr>
   <td><?php echo $clents['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $clents['email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $days.(($days == 1) ? " day" : " days"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor("admin/user_view_data/{$clents['email']}",'Send Mail',array('class'=>'btn btn-info'));?></td>
  <?php endforeach;?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

this is not calculate according to email , this added whole value  email by email

i have same email id multiple time like`test@test.com` and there time also multiple how to add time according to email and show email id not duplicate entry.

i have no idea please help me . thanks
here is the output:

Comment: This has no sense: `if($clents['email']==$clents['email'])` it will always be true, what do you wanted to do?

Comment: i know but i have no idea?

Comment: also, in $days you are summing the days for all the users

Comment: i want to add days when same  email id

Comment: the foreach goes row by row, so what you do inside it will be done for each row

Comment: ok, I write an answer

Comment: how ? please help me

Comment: thanks for your help.

Comment: if there are 2 rows with same "email" but different "id", which id do you want to show in the table?

Comment: there are two- five row with same email but different id i want to add same email  value time.

Comment: yes but in the column id, what id do you want to show? The first column (12, 13, 14...)

Comment: only one  id with same email (any) not matter  any

Comment: why you do $days = 30 - $fullDays? I don't understand

Comment: just suppose you  apply for a member today and your member ship valid for next 30 days in between you payed then your membership  valid   left days + upcoming days

Comment: mmm but if $fulldays is 60 days, it will be 30-60=-30...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your trying to calculate something like this is it .

if mm@gmail.com days =2;
again mm@gmail.com days =5;

you need both of mm@gmail.com days =7;

try this

```html
<?php if(count($client)): ?>
  <?php $days=0;
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

 $NEW_ARRAY =array();
    ?>
  $i=1;

   <?php foreach ($client as $clents) { ?>
    <?php
  
     if($i==1)
  {
    $today = time();
    $cdate = strtotime($clents['times']);
    $dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
    $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    $dayscalculate = 30 - $fullDays; // Set number of days ?>

     <?php $day=$dayscalculate; 
   
   $NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]=$day
    
    //  $days +=$day;
   
   
    
   }
 else if(array_key_exists($clents['email'],$NEW_ARRAY))
 {
 
   
   $today = time();
    $cdate = strtotime($clents['times']);
    $dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
    $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    $dayscalculate = 30 - $fullDays; // Set number of days ?>

     <?php $day=$dayscalculate; 
   
   $NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]=$NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]+$day;
    
  // $days +=$day;
 
 
 }
 else
 {
 
   $today = time();
    $cdate = strtotime($clents['times']);
    $dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
    $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    $dayscalculate = 30 - $fullDays; // Set number of days ?>

     <?php $day=$dayscalculate; 
   
    $NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]=$NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]+$day;
    
  // $days +=$day;
 
 
 
 }
 
 $i++;
  }
```

Comment: your logic is correct but last else condition showing error `$NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]=$NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]+$day;` with some email id

Comment: last else condition you just change the days count line like this                         $NEW_ARRAY[$clents['email']]=$day;    because this mail id new entry so u have to store that  as a new one .

Comment: one more help need how to short array value using there value

Comment: like ascending or descending any clue.?

Comment: sort() - sort arrays in ascending order
rsort() - sort arrays in descending order
asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
ksort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
arsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
krsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to get the difference between two dates:
From the first picture (database tables), i took the example of ID:17

```
$today = new DateTime("now");
$clientDateString = $clents['times'];
$clientDate = date_create($clientDateString);

$dateInterval =  date_diff($clientDate, $today);
echo $dateInterval->format('%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to calculate the days if the date is entered without the time.

```
$to_date = strtotime($to_date);
$from_date = strtotime($from_date);
$datediff = $to_date - $from_date;
$days = $datediff / (60 * 60 * 24) + 1;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if I have understood:

```
<table>
<?php

if(count($client)): 
    $days = 0;
    $today = time();
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    $all_clients = array(); // This array will contain the final data

    foreach ($client as $clents):

        $cdate = strtotime($clents['times']);
        $dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
        $days = 30-floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));

        if(!isset($all_clients[$clents['email']]))
        {
            // This cliens is already in the array, add the number of days
            $all_clients[$clents['email']] = [
                'id' => $clents['id'],
                'email' => $clents['email'],
                'days' => $days,
            ];
        }
        else
        {
            // Add the new days to the existing
            $all_clients[$clents['email']]['days'] += $days;
        }

    endforeach;


    foreach($all_clients as $client):
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $client['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $client['email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $client['days'] . (($client['days'] == 1) ? " day" : " days"); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor("admin/user_view_data/{$client['email']}", 'Send Mail', array('class'=>'btn btn-info'));?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    endforeach;
endif;

?>
</table>
```

Comment: ok I've edited it, it's because you're using a old version of php

Comment: getting  value for not added there value  other's same email value only one email value showing

Comment: Sorry i don't understand

Comment: just suppose i have  `test@test.com` this email  have 5 times in database now i want to calculate all those email field date(in days) and show  how many days remaining

Comment: just suppose you have paid today for member ship  for 30 days after 10 days you have paid  another payment now your membership days (20+30) this value i want to show with that user, if user pay another payment  in same day then (20+30+30) how to do this any idea you have.